# Using Drush with ENVVARS

Tags: 7, drush, database

I use EnvVars (vhost) to set my MySQL settings so I can have cross-server settings.php file without having to update it 3 different times.

I am wondering if there is a way to get drush to do one of the following.

1. Read the EnvVars from the VHOST (in which case where so I find the Drush database config gathering stuff).
2. Override the MySQL settings for pm-update

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing Drush feature request.  See http://drupal.org/node/1848766 and http://drupal.org/node/1335626.

You could also make a bash alias (one per Drupal site) that set the appropriate environment variables, and then called Drush.